# set temDir and outputpath via python script

Tags: python, scripting

I have to use blender 2.49 and I am trying to change a few settings via a python script like resolution etc. - everything is working but the tmpDir and the outputpath - which I want to change from `/tmp/ to /local/` for example

I am using the [blender 2.49 api](http://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/) and it should be:

```
bpy.config.tempDir = "/local/" 
bpy.config.renderDir = "Path I want"
```

but this is not working so far.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you srill using 2.49?